# Put div on top of everything even on top of inbuild pop-up windows also

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two forms, one is takes input from user while another form (pop-up window) executes data and display the result to user. Sometimes 2nd form i.e. pop-up window requires more time to executes data, so user close that pop-up window as he/she feels there is network issue.
So I want to prevent user from closing that pop-up window. So I think extra div on top of everything will sort my issue. I have tried few examples also, but it won't fix my problem. I want to put div on top of pop-up window. Is it possible? Please help me.

Comment: Create jsfiddle or post your code.

Comment: Use `position:fixed or absolute` and `z-index`

Comment: or is there any way to hide title bar, so user can not close the window

Comment: the maximum u can do is give an alert this way- `window.onbeforeunload = function closingTab() {
        return "Are you sure to close";
    }`

Answer (score 0):

If by pop-up window you mean the browser's own pop-up windows, that's impossible. Because in this case you will need to change the browser code which is not a thing to achieve.
What I would suggest to you to do is, while you are doing the processing in the background -it does not matter how long it takes- show some process bars opr information messages to the user.

Comment: Thanks Cengiz.. Yeah I am trying to add loader as soon as clicks on process button. but the pop-up window is open on top of that loader. and then user clicks on close(X) button, if it takes time. that i want to stop.

Comment: if you are able to create a jsfiddle for this situation, I would try to help.

Comment: actually I don't know any idea about jsfiddle. should i post my code where i try this thing?

Comment: it s a website that you load your html/css and javascript code. In this community if you are asking a direct answer generally you would post your code section in here or into jsfiddle website.

Answer (score 0):

U can have a overlay with a very high z-index say 9999 and remove the overlay when your operation is complete say call functions- `openNav()` and `closeNav()` to open/close the overlay each time.

Some code from the site [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 9999;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.9);
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.overlay-content {
    position: relative;
    top: 25%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

overlay a {font-size: 20px}
  .overlay .closebtn {
    font-size: 40px;
    top: 15px;
    right: 35px;
  }
}
</style>
<body>

<div id="myNav" class="overlay">
  
  <div class="overlay-content">
  <div style="color:white;">Wait ...</div>  
  </div>
</div>



<script>
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "100%";
}

setTimeout(function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("myNav").style.width = "0%";
},4000);  
  
openNav();
</script>
     
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution for it.

After submitting the form, present the pop-up to the user. In the pop-up add a loading animation. So that user knows something is working in the background. You can easily add loading animations by http://loading.io/

Once the calculations from the form are complete, remove that loading animation and put the computed value to that div so that it replaces that div. You will need javascript or jquery for that.

Comment: Thanks Gijo.. I have already tried this concept; but user clicks on close(X) button after few minutes. Even they don't have patience also. I will implement what you have said, if I didn't achieve what I want to?

Comment: Remove that close button ;) But why its taking 'minutes'?? No one waits that much!

Another solution is, put that loading animation next to the button in the form. When the calculation is complete show the popup with the result

Comment: Try modals from bootstrap, its very good http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: @RajKhot Pls upvote/accept my answer if it helped you